# SQL Email showing sent but customer and CC email also not receive

Tags: sql-server

I'm facing some problem from SQL Email server I sent email to customer. email database showing sent but customer and CC email also not receive evening i checked spam folder also

I checked following table

```
select sent_status, *  
from msdb..sysmail_allitems 
order by mailitem_id desc;
```

Results are showing sent but I and customer did not receive any email:

```
sent    8931    2017    testEmail@gmail.com NULL    testEmail2@gmail.com    Test    Test b  HTML
sent    8930    2017    testEmail@gmail.com NULL    testEmail2@gmail.com    Test    Test b  HTML
```

I want to know why the status is showing as 'sent', and why customer and me did not receive an e-mail.

Comment: Could be anything. What does the SMTP server logs show?